# How to cleanup data in list format in a dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, dataset

I have data in excel which I am trying to cleanup in Python using pandas. There are almost 150 columns and 10 of those have values in list format in cells. Now while exploding and shifting to rows they are getting multiplied for every column I am exploding and it is increasing the number of rows unnecessarily. I also don't want to shift data to columns as it would create almost 120 extra columns according to dataset I have. So is there any way to cleanup this type of data so that I can upload to an SQL server and apply queries and perform searches and analysis further.

Comment: In what format do you want to keep this data? You don't want new rows or columns, maybe you should just save the list as a string?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by 'values in list format in cells': is it a comma-separated list of values? Perhaps show some example data.

Comment: @BorutFlis I am confused as to what should I keep the format of my dataframe. 
Consider that I have a dataset of 10 students. Now the columns are Name, Age, Marks, Subjects, Sports. And in 'Marks','Subject' and 'Sports' columns we have list values like Maths,Science,English in a cell. Now If I use,
df = df.assign(Marks=df.Marks.str.split(",")).explode('Marks')
then it will shift to rows and other metrics is also repeated.
Now when getting the details of some Student using query or while plotting graph this repetition might create an issue. 
So what format should I use in this case ?

Comment: Do the values in Marks correspond to the values in Subjects? what is the relationship between them. Perhaps you can output your current dataframe to get a better understanding.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.